# Macro should copy data from One sheet & paste in different format in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA, hence I need your help to do this task.

Currently I have a sheet called "Sample_Raw_Data" where I have all raw details.

Now I want to copy each row from "Sample_Raw_Data" and and split into 22 rows (i.e. 5 years 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018 and 2019 also in each year 4 types of fee details) and paste in the below format in a different sheet

==================================================================================

## Group, Medium, Subject, State, District, City, Sales SubRegion1, Fee Details, Year, Total Fees

Can someone please let me know the VBA code to do this task?

I have already updated the sample one row of data from "Sample_Raw_Data" and pasted into 21 different rows in "Macro Results" sheet.

Here is the attachment link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s9y5oyq07kwgary/Sample%20Data.xlsx

Thank you so much for your help in advance

Best Regards
Amrutha

Comment: Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: This reads like homework.  Pass on doing this for you.

Comment: What have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. [See here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Dear All,  I could able to get the code with my friends help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I could able to get the below code with my friends help.

```
Sub splitData()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsSample As Worksheet
Dim wsMacro As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Integer
Dim wRow As Long

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsSample = wb.Worksheets("Sample_Raw_Data")
Set wsMacro = wb.Worksheets("Macro Results")
lr = wsSample.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row of data in column A

Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With wsMacro
    For i = 5 To lr
        If Not IsEmpty(wsSample.Range("a" & i)) Then
            wRow = .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1   'WRITE row in Macro sheet
            For j = 1 To 7
                .Cells(wRow, j) = wsSample.Cells(i, j)
            Next j
            .Cells(wRow, 8) = "Base Fees"
            .Cells(wRow, 9) = "2014"
            .Cells(wRow, 10) = wsSample.Cells(i, 8)
            
            .Range("a" & wRow & ":g" & wRow).Copy
            .Range("a" & wRow + 1 & ":a" & wRow + 20).PasteSpecial
            
            .Range("h" & wRow + 1 & ":h" & wRow + 5).Value = "Hostel Fees"
            For j = 1 To 5
                .Cells(wRow + j, 9) = 2014 + j
                .Cells(wRow + j, 10) = wsSample.Cells(i, 9 + ((j - 1) * 5))
            Next j
            .Range("h" & wRow + 6 & ":h" & wRow + 10).Value = "Books"
            For j = 1 To 5
                .Cells(wRow + 5 + j, 9) = 2014 + j
                .Cells(wRow + 5 + j, 10) = wsSample.Cells(i, 10 + ((j - 1) * 5))
            Next j
            .Range("h" & wRow + 11 & ":h" & wRow + 15).Value = "Dress"
            For j = 1 To 5
                .Cells(wRow + 10 + j, 9) = 2014 + j
                .Cells(wRow + 10 + j, 10) = wsSample.Cells(i, 11 + ((j - 1) * 5))
            Next j
            .Range("h" & wRow + 16 & ":h" & wRow + 20).Value = "Tuition"
            For j = 1 To 5
                .Cells(wRow + 15 + j, 9) = 2014 + j
                .Cells(wRow + 15 + j, 10) = wsSample.Cells(i, 12 + ((j - 1) * 5))
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    .Range("a1:j1").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.WindowState = xlNormal
```

End Sub

Comment: Now the problem is I am banned to post new questions.  Can someone please help me or what should I do to lift that ban?